# Android Studio cannot re-import module

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm posting this in hopes to help several folks who may be struggling the same way I am. I was just trying to fix my run configuration for a basic Android project in Android Studio when things went haywire. Ever since 2 updates ago my run config stopped working. It was somehow pointing to an apk path that had been changed. Something in the latest AS updates changes where the apk is built to without updating existing run configs. Long story lengthened…

I tried creating a new run config then tried running the old config. I got an error saying that I probably needed to sync my project with my Gradle build file. I clicked the "Refresh all GRadle Projects" sync-looking button in the Gradle tasks window when everything went awry. My module completely disappeared from the project! I tried re-importing from project settings  then I started to get an error:

```
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip
```

I couldn't figure this out because I didn't have this problem earlier and also I noticed my module file had been completely deleted! I tried a few more times before looking at the Android Studio logs which said something about it couldn't unzip the gradle 1.8 bundle or something. I realized it was trying to download something and that I was on paid wifi in an airport so the download couldn't complete. I then payed for wifi so that the download could complete and tried re-importing the project. I STILL got the error! After few more attempts I decided to check under ~/.gradle where I found and deleted "wrapper/dists/gradle-1.8-bin folder thinking the earlier download was corrupt and confusing AS. That seemed to get things going again as the next attempt triggered a download/install of something that allowed me to continue to the next step.

I'm currently still trying to re-import and set the module up again and it feels like a lot of re-work. I eventually got to a point where I was told my version of gradle was too old... (I have Gradle-1.7) I'm just throwing this out there now in case anyone else hits their head the way I just did. It can be an expensive mistake. (I'm still paying for Wifi so I can send this!)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured out my issue. My build.gradle was set to use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+', which is incompatible with the latest version of Android Studio. After duplicating my project folder in Finder, updating to the latest Gradle, and tweaking the plugin version I am finally able to sync my project. I hope this post saves someone else a headache!